# Groovy - Parse XML Response, Select Fields, Create New File

Tags: json, file, dictionary, groovy, xml-parsing

I think I've read every Groovy parsing question on here but I can't seem to find my exact scenario so I'm reaching out for help - please be kind, I'm new to Groovy and I've really bitten off more than I can chew in this latest endeavor.

So I have this XML Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<worklogs date_from="2020-04-19 00:00:00" date_to="2020-04-25 23:59:59" number_of_worklogs="60" format="xml" diffOnly="false" errorsOnly="false" validOnly="false" addDeletedWorklogs="true" addBillingInfo="false" addIssueSummary="true" addIssueDescription="false" duration_ms="145" headerOnly="false" userName="smm288" addIssueDetails="false" addParentIssue="false" addUserDetails="true" addWorklogDetails="false" billingKey="" issueKey="" projectKey="" addApprovalStatus="true" >
    <worklog>
        <worklog_id></worklog_id>
        <jira_worklog_id></jira_worklog_id>
        <issue_id></issue_id>
        <issue_key></issue_key>
        <hours></hours>
        <work_date></work_date>
        <username></username>
        <staff_id />
        <billing_key></billing_key>
        <billing_attributes></billing_attributes>
        <activity_id></activity_id>
        <activity_name></activity_name>
        <work_description></work_description>
        <parent_key></parent_key>
        <reporter></reporter>
        <external_id />
        <external_tstamp />
        <external_hours></external_hours>
        <external_result />
        <customField_11218></customField_11218>
        <customField_12703></customField_12703>
        <customField_12707></customField_12707>
        <hash_value></hash_value>
        <issue_summary></issue_summary>
        <user_details>
            <full_name></full_name>
            <email></email>
            <user-prop key="auto_approve_timesheet"></user-prop>
            <user-prop key="cris_id"></user-prop>
            <user-prop key="iqn_gl_string"></user-prop>
            <user-prop key="is_contractor"></user-prop>
            <user-prop key="is_employee"></user-prop>
            <user-prop key="it_leadership"></user-prop>
            <user-prop key="primary_role"></user-prop>
            <user-prop key="resource_manager"></user-prop>
            <user-prop key="team"></user-prop>
        </user_details>
        <approval_status></approval_status>
        <timesheet_approval>
            <status></status>
            <status_date></status_date>
            <reviewer></reviewer>
            <actor></actor>
            <comment></comment>
        </timesheet_approval>
    </worklog>
    ....
    ....
</worklogs>
```

And I'm retrieving this XML Response from an API call so the response is held within an object. **NOTE:** The sample XML above is from Postman.

What I'm trying to do is the following:
1. Only retrieve certain values from this response from all the nodes. 
2. Write the values collected to a .json file.

I've created a map but now I'm kind of stuck on how to parse through it and create a .json file out of the fields I want.

This is what I have thus far

```
@Grab('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1')
@Grab('oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2')
@Grab('oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2')

import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import groovyx.net.http.Method
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.*

// User Credentials
def jiraAuth = ""

// JIRA Endpoints
def jiraUrl = "" //Dev
def jiraUrl = "" //Production

// Tempo API Tokens
//def tempoApiToken = "" //Dev
//def tempoApiToken = "" //Production

// Define Weekly Date Range
def today = new Date()
def lastPeriodStart = today - 8
def lastPeriodEnd = today - 2
def dateFrom = lastPeriodStart.format("yyyy-MM-dd")
def dateTo = lastPeriodEnd.format("yyyy-MM-dd")

def jiraClient = new RESTClient(jiraUrl)
jiraClient.ignoreSSLIssues()

def headers = [
    "Authorization"    : "Basic " + jiraAuth,
    "X-Atlassian-token": "no-check",
    "Content-Type"     : "application/json"
]

def response = jiraClient.get(
    path: "",
    query: [
        tempoApiToken: "${tempoApiToken}",
        format: "xml",
        dateFrom: "${dateFrom}",
        dateTo: "${dateTo}",
        addUserDetails: "true",
        addApprovalStatus: "true",
        addIssueSummary: "true"
    ],
    headers: headers
    ) { response, worklogs ->

    println "Processing..."

    // Start building the Output - Creates a Worklog Map
    worklogs.worklog.each { worklognodes ->

        def workLog = convertToMap(worklognodes)

        // Print out the Map
        println (workLog)
    }
}

// Helper Method
def convertToMap(nodes) {
    nodes.children().collectEntries {
        if (it.name() == 'user-prop') {
            [it['@key'], it.childNodes() ? convertToMap(it) : it.text()]
        } else {
            [it.name(), it.childNodes() ? convertToMap(it) : it.text()]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm only interested in parsing out the following fields from each node:

```
<worklogs>
    <worklog>
        <hours>
        <work_date>
        <billing_key>
        <customField_11218>
        <issue_summary>
        <user_details>
            <full_name>
            <user-prop key="auto_approve_timesheet">
            <user-prop key="it_leadership">
            <user-prop key="resource_manager">
            <user-prop key="team">
            <user-prop key="cris_id">
            <user-prop key="iqn_id">
        <approval_status>
    </worklog>
    ...
</worklogs>
```

I've tried the following:
1. Converting the `workLog` to a json string (JsonOutput.toJson) and then converting the json string to prettyPrint (JsonOutput.prettyPrint) - but this just returns a collection of .json responses which I can't do anything with (thought process was, this is as good as I can get and I'll just use a .json to .csv converter and get rid of what I don't want) - which is not the solution I ultimately want. 
2. Printing the map `workLog` just returns little collections which I can't do anything with either
3. Create a new file using `File` and creating a .json file of `workLog` but again, it doesn't translate well.

The results of the `println` for `workLog` is here (just so everyone can see that the response is being held and the map matches the XML response).

```
[worklog_id: , jira_worklog_id: , issue_id: , issue_key: , hours: , work_date: , username: , staff_id: , billing_key: , billing_attributes: , activity_id: , activity_name: , work_description: , parent_key: , reporter: , external_id:, external_tstamp:, external_hours: , external_result:, customField_11218: , hash_value: , issue_summary: , user_details:[full_name: , email: , auto_approve_timesheet: , cris_id: , iqn_gl_approver: , iqn_gl_string: , iqn_id: , is_contractor: , is_employee: , it_leadership: , primary_role: , resource_manager: , team: ], approval_status: , timesheet_approval:[status: ]]
```

I would so appreciate it if anyone could offer some insights on how to move forward or even documentation that has good examples of what I'm trying to achieve (Apache's documentation is sorely lacking in examples, in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

It's not all of the way there. But, I was able to get a JSON file created with the XML and Map. From there I can just use the .json file to create a .csv and then get rid of the columns I don't want.

```
// Define Weekly Date Range
def today = new Date()
def lastPeriodStart = today - 8
def lastPeriodEnd = today - 2
def dateFrom = lastPeriodStart.format("yyyy-MM-dd")
def dateTo = lastPeriodEnd.format("yyyy-MM-dd")

def jiraClient = new RESTClient(jiraUrl)
jiraClient.ignoreSSLIssues()

// Creates and Begins the File
File file = new File("${dateFrom}_RPT05.json")
    file.write("")
    file.append("[\n")

// Defines the File
def arrplace = 0
def arrsize = 0

def headers = [
    "Authorization"    : "Basic " + jiraAuth,
    "X-Atlassian-token": "no-check",
    "Content-Type"     : "application/json"
]

def response = jiraClient.get(
    path: "/plugins/servlet/tempo-getWorklog/",
    query: [    
        tempoApiToken: "${tempoApiToken}",
        format: "xml",
        dateFrom: "${dateFrom}",
        dateTo: "${dateTo}",
        addUserDetails: "true",
        addApprovalStatus: "true",
        addIssueSummary: "true"
    ], 
    headers: headers
    ) { response, worklogs ->

    println "Processing..."

    // Gets Size of Array
    worklogs.worklog.each { worklognodes ->
    arrsize = arrsize+1 }

    // Start Building the Output - Creates a Worklog Map 
    worklogs.worklog.each { worklognodes ->
        worklognodes = convertToMap(worklognodes)

        // Convert Map to a JSON String
        def json_str = JsonOutput.toJson(worklognodes)

        // Adds Row to File
        file.append(json_str)
        arrplace = arrplace+1
        if(arrplace<arrsize)
        {file.append(",")}
        file.append("\n")
        print "."
        }
    }

    file.append("]")

// Helper Method
def convertToMap(nodes) {
    nodes.children().collectEntries {
        if (it.name() == 'user-prop') {
            [it['@key'], it.childNodes() ? convertToMap(it) : it.text()]
        } else {
            [it.name(), it.childNodes() ? convertToMap(it) : it.text()]
        }
    }
}
```

The output is a collection/array of worklogs.